# Change header based on parent product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I am running an e-commerce store where I have two custom headers for different sides of the store. I am wondering if is possible that for:

- the parent product category A to display header A
- the parent product category B to display header B

I just don't know where to put it in my theme.

Here is my actual code example:

```
if(is_category('category-a-slug')){
    get_header('a');
}elseif(is_category('category-b-slug')){
    get_header('b');
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get a different header based on the parent product category, use the following code:

```
// For product category archive pages only
if(is_product_category()){
    // Get the WP_Term object for the current product category
    $queried_obj = get_queried_object();
    $parent_id   = $queried_obj->parent; // The parent term ID
    $taxonomy    = $queried_obj->taxonomy; // The taxonomy
    
    // If a parent term id exist, we get the parent term slug
    if( $parent_id > 0 ){
        $parent_slug = get_term_by( 'term_id', $parent_id, $taxonomy )->slug;
    }
    
    // If a parent slug exist and for parent term slug 'category-a-slug'
    if ( isset($parent_slug) && $parent_slug == 'category-a-slug' ) {
        get_header('a');
    } 
    // If a parent slug exist and for parent term slug 'category-b-slug'
    elseif ( isset($parent_slug) && $parent_slug == 'category-b-slug' ) {
        get_header('b');
    } 
    // Other cases
    else {
        get_header('shop');
    }
// For other Woocommerce archives types (as shop)
} else {
    get_header('shop');
}
```

It should work.

> Code goes on Woocommerce template [`archive-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php) replacing `get_header('shop');`
>
> See: [How to override Woocommerce templates via the active theme (documentation)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)